# Export my custom grid data's in Xls

Tags: magento-1.8, export

How to export my custom grid data's in xls format in Magento Admin panel grid.

In default we having the csv and xml format.

[image]

Anyone help me on it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this below code:

```
$this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('{module}')->__('Excel'));
public function exportExcelAction()  
{  
    $fileName   = 'excel_name.xls';
    $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('{module}/adminhtml_{module}_grid')->getExcelFile();
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);  
}
```

also refer [here](http://vijay-magento-store.blogspot.in/)

Comment: Wow this is great! I wondered why they were using xml all the time instead of xls, but never knew if they had Excel. Your reply gave me the answer. Thanks.